# std::reverse on MFC CArray

Tags: c++, stl, mfc

I have an array of points like this:

```
CArray<CPoint,CPoint> points;
```

And I need to reverse the order of the points. I've tried this method:

```
std::reverse( &points[0], &points[0] + points.GetSize() );
```

And it works. Then I've tried this other method:

```
std::reverse( &points[0], &points[points.GetUpperBound()] );
```

But it doesn't work: the last item is not ordered correctly. Why?

Comment: `CArray` is not as important as `CString` You should consider `vector` instead, unless `CArray` is already in your code.

Comment: Absolutely, but I'm adding new functionalities in an ... ancient piece of code based on MFC and I'm not allowed to change too much things.

Comment: By the way, that's a neat trick how you get that to work with the first method. I guess that's safe!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because STL algorithms take ranges in the form *[b, e)* (that is, *e* exclusive), whereas [the function you used returns the position of the last actual last element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

It should be further noted that your second form is even more problematic in the case where the array is empty. The function, according to the documentation, returns -1 in this case. BOOM!

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s68se708.aspx) says that `GetUpperBound()` returns the index of the last element, so `&points[points.GetUpperBound()]` represents an iterator to the last element, while STL algorithms require half-open ranges like `[begin, end)`, that is, `end` must point *directly after the last element*.

Answer (score 2):

First, while STL's algorithms (including `std::reverse()`) are designed to work fine with STL containers or STL-compatible containers (i.e. those providing STL-compatible iterators), I'm not sure about combining them with *MFC containers*.
Certainly, MFC containers were *not* designed with STL algorithm compatibility in mind.

I'd suggest to move your code from using MFC containers like `CArray` to more modern containers like `std::vector`.

That said, in the second case here:

> ```
> std::reverse( &points[0], &points[points.GetUpperBound()] );
> ```

the second *"iterator"* argument that you pass to `std::reverse()` is *not* pointing to **one-past** the last valid item (like in the first case of  `&points[0] + points.GetSize()`), but it's actually pointing to **the last valid item**.

In fact, [`CArray::GetUpperBound()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s68se708.aspx) returns the last valid index (from MSDN documentation):

> Because array indexes are zero-based, this function returns a value 1
>   less than `GetSize`.

You may be tempted to use something like `&points[points.GetSize()]` or `&points[points.GetUpperBound() + 1]`, but those would fail, since `CArray` overloads `operator[]`, implementing bound checking at least in debug builds.
And with these aforementioned alternatives, you end up using an index out of the valid range.

But, let me repeat: consider moving your code from `CArray` to `std::vector`. You can still use MFC for the front-end GUI of your application; but for the "core" of your application, for the "business logic", using modern C++ and STL containers is a better option.

Comment: So in your opinion is not safe to use std::reverse? It would be better if I write my own implementation for CArray? Unfortunately I'm not allowed to move from 'CArray' to 'std::vector'

Comment: [`std:::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) works also on raw C-like arrays. If `CArray` stores its stuff contiguously in memory like raw arrays, you may do some testing using `std::reverse( &points[0], &points[0] + points.GetSize() );` and you may use that. I don't know if `CArray` has some internal implementation details that somehow conflicts with `std::reverse`. You may want to study `CArray`'s source. However, the solid thing to me is to use `std::vector` instead of `CArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You could reverse the array link this using a stack:

```
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

void ReverseArray(CArray<CPoint,CPoint> points, int n)
{
    // create an empty stack of integers
    stack<CPoint,CPoint> stack;

    // push each array element into a stack
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        stack.push(points[i]);
    }

    // start from index 0
    int index = 0;

    // pop values from the stack until it becomes empty
    while (!stack.empty())
    {
        // assign each popped item back to the original array
        points[index++] = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
    }
}
```

For details, please see https://www.techiedelight.com/reverse-an-array-cpp/